# Where is it specified that some piece of code need to deployed as Lambda Function using "amplify add function"

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm going through a codebase but unable to understand how amplify taking local code to lambda function:

I have below file structure:
[image]

Here `myLambda1`, `myLambda2` contains code of `my-lambda-1` and `my-lambda-2` respectively. But I'm unable to figure it out where is it specified that `myLambda1` should take code of `my-lambda-1`